# RewriteRule on alias url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, kohana

on query:

```
domain.com/page/do
```

i need:

```
domain.com/index.php/page/do
```

etc.

i use htaccess file, i add alias

```
RewriteBase /index.php/
```

How i write RewriteRule to this url?

Comment: This is a common rewrite rule. See [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/265934/150634) for examples.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should do what you want, and eliminate the need to have index.php in your uri

```
###
# Rewrite Rules
#

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    ### Enable mod_rewrite

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    ### Checks if the URI request path coincides with a literal path
    ### on the filesystem relative to the webroot. If it does not exist,
    ### then it passes the path through index.php.

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$  /$1/$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond ^/index.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```