# Rewrite PHP all GET parameters .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mod_rewrite, php and the .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265898/mod-rewrite-php-and-the-htaccess-file)

Would like this to happen in the .htaccess file.
to rewrite

```
index.php?pagetype=name
```

to

```
/pagetype/name/
```

do this for all pagetypes so

```
?user=name
?post=number
?life=sucks ... etc
```

but would like to exclude

```
/css/
/images/
/js/
/php/
/template/
```

so the variable links still work.

I am guessing this should work but I want it in it's most simplest form so I don't have to change the .htaccess file everytime I add a pagetype.

I did a search for this but didn't find anything helpful.

The site will only have one physically accessed file: index.php then the rest are processed via $_GET commands

Comment: No, you want to rewrite the (incoming SEO/SEF format URI) `/pagetype/name/` to `/index.php?pagetype=name` (which your PHP code can digest). Please get the terminology right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the example you specified, the simplest approach would be:

```
 RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}   !^/(css|images|js|php|template)/
 RewriteRule  ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$  index.php?$1=$2  [QSA,L]
```

(The RewriteCond could be written as negative lookeahead in the Rule instead of course.)

See also the [mod-rewrite tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info) for further howtos.

Comment: Fantastic - thanks so much would you be able to add a little comment to that to explain it please.
Worked brilliant, thanks.

Comment: Which parts need explanation? All of them? That's what the manual is for.

Comment: Thought it would be cheaky to ask, I'll give it a read. htaccess isn't something I have looked at in any detail yet but thanks.

Comment: One more thing - How can I do it backwards, as if 
    site.com/index.php?page=name
rewrites to
    site.com/page/name/

Comment: Not at all. mod_rewrites incoming URLs, not outgoing ones. Change the application code that generates links.